# outdated stunnel,openssl versions Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, openssl

I have :
stunnel 4.53 > when the latest version is 5.31
openssl 1.0.1f > when the latest version is 1.0.2g
I've updated the system using apt-get but still with 4.53 and 1.0.1f , I have a security concern that it's not good to be with such outdated versions ? why ubuntu doesn't provide the latest versions ? and how to update them please ?

Comment: Most likely any security issues are already patched, even if the version # isn't latest.

Comment: so you say to stick with the latest updates and don't try to update the softwares manually ? I had also openvpn 2.3.2 and updated it through the openvpn official repo to 2.3.10

Answer (score 0):

In the versions in the official repositories, all known security vulnerabilities are fixed, so if you are only concerned about security you can just stick with the Ubuntu version. If you have a particular vulnerability in mind, you can read the Ubuntu changelog (in `/usr/share/doc` or on http://packages.ubuntu.com, for example) to confirm that it is fixed in the Ubuntu package.

You may, however, want new features not available in the Ubuntu version, and in that case upgrading yourself is necessary, for example with repositories provided by the developers as in the case of OpenVPN.